# How to reuse WPF custome window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created custome window (titlebar, min/max/ext buttons, own border for window manipulation and lots of styles and triggers).

There are 5 methods defined (which i would like to override):

From window markup:

```
SourceInitialized="Window_SourceInitialized"

Closing="Window_Closing"
```

From Titlebar buttons:

```
Exit_Click()

Max_Click()

Min_Click()
```

And at last I have `DockPanel`

```
<DockPanel Name="ClientArea"/>
```

In which I want to put my content

I have tried to add content from code:

```
BaseWindow editInterfaceWindow = new BaseWindow() { Owner = this };                  
editInterfaceWindow.DataContext = new EditInterface();
editInterfaceWindow.ShowDialog();
```

But this way some bindings stoped working and inside editInterfaceWindow I cant create another window this way because of `Owner = this`. There are also some problems with `InitializeComponent()` in constructor.
And ListView inside EditInterface UserControl `<ListView Name="LBAvaliable" ItemsSource="{Binding AvaliableFaces, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">` is not visible in code as LBAvaliable.

I have used that window few times, filling ClientArea with content by hand.
How should I create other windows, so that I can just inherit it or just define binding? So my XAML for every single window does not take ~1000 lines of code.

Comment: I'm not familiar with inheriting windows in WPF but take a look at UserControls. It allows you to re-use an existing custom control.

Comment: EditInterface in my example is actualy that UserControl and I have tried to do that

Comment: one way would be to create an empty, clean class that inherits from the base window class, add your methods there (i think you could even make them abstract) and then have your actual windows inherit from *that* class instead of the base window class.

Comment: On a sidenote; i like @JohnEphraimTugado 's solution better

Comment: If I use that solution like `<UserControl Name="ClientArea" Content="{Binding}"/>` and just set my UserControl as DataContext; Inside a Window that shows up is only that UserControl and my BaseWindow is not visible.
https://imgur.com/a/x6MQz

Answer (score 1):

In the past I've used [MVVMCross Framework](https://www.mvvmcross.com/) and we never had to worry about this ourselves. Though this is not the best, here's an idea on what you can do.

1. Create a view model that can be overridden for your user control.
2. Set data templates.
3. Programmatically change the view model for your user control's main content and let data templates do the work for the UI.

View Model: Pre-defined 3 button actions ready for you to set/override.

```
public class MainUCViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Action<object> btnACommand;
    private Action<object> btnBCommand;
    private Action<object> btnCCommand;

    private object ccVM;

    public ViewModelBase CCVM
    {
        get { return this.ccVM; }
        set
        {
            this.ccVM = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(); // Notify View
        }
    }

    public MainUCViewModel()
    {

    }

    public RelayCommand BtnACommand
    {
        get { return new RelayCommand(btnACommand); }
    }

    public RelayCommand BtnBCommand
    {
        get { return new RelayCommand(btnBCommand); }
    }

    public RelayCommand BtnCCommand
    {
        get { return new RelayCommand(btnCCommand); }
    }

    public void SetBtnACommand(Action<object> action)
    {
        this.btnACommand = action;
    }

    public void SetBtnBCommand(Action<object> action)
    {
        this.btnBCommand = action;
    }

    public void SetBtnCCommand(Action<object> action)
    {
        this.btnCCommand = action;
    }
}
```

View:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.Views.UserControls.MainUC"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="750">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="45" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Command="{Binding BtnACommand}" Width="100">
                    <TextBlock>A</TextBlock>
                </Button>
                <Rectangle Width="15" />
                <Button Command="{Binding BtnBCommand}" Width="100">
                    <TextBlock>B</TextBlock>
                </Button>
                <Rectangle Width="15" />
                <Button Command="{Binding BtnCCommand}" Width="100">
                    <TextBlock>C</TextBlock>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <ContentControl x:Name="CCMain" Content="{Binding CCVM}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Look at [Thinking with MVVM: Data Templates + ContentControl](http://www.japf.fr/2009/03/thinking-with-mvvm-data-templates-contentcontrol/). Simply define the data template for your view model.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:GeneralSettingsViewModel}">
        <View:GeneralSettingsView/>
    </DataTemplate
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:AdvancedSettingsViewModel}">
        <View:AdvancedSettingsView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

> What I’m saying here is that GeneralSettingsViewModel should be
>   rendered using a GeneralSettingsView. That’s exactly what we need !
>   Because the Views are created using a DataTemplate, we do not need to
>   setup the DataContext, it will be automatically registered to the
>   templated object, the ViewModel.

Comment: I think you may answered my question but give me more time for testing

Comment: @Iluvatar I've just finished testing this one and it worked. Take note of the change to `<ContentControl x:Name="CCMain" Content="{Binding CCVM}"/>`

Answer (score 0):

There are two main approaches to your problem:

1. Inherited windows
2. Configurable windows

For approach 1, design your window and make the methods overrideable:

In base window xaml, assign the handlers and everything you want:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTests.MainWindow"
    ...
    SourceInitialized="Window_SourceInitialized">
```

In base window, define the handlers as `protected virtual` (or `abstract`, if you like to enforce their implementation)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    // ...

    protected virtual void Window_SourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    // ...
}
```

Create derived windows

```
public class ExWindow : MainWindow
{
    protected override void Window_SourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // specialized code here
    }
}
```

Change App.xaml to use `Startup` instead of `StartupUri`

```
<Application x:Class="WpfTests.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         Startup="Application_Startup">
```

And manually create your first window, chosing one of the inherited window classes

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        var window = new ExWindow();
        window.Show();
    }
}
```

---

The second approach - configurable windows - follows the same principle as a good user control design: The window/control properties are controlled by the creator instead of being controlled by the window/control itself.

So, instead of defining some event handler within the window code, just leave this exercise to the user, who hopefully knows what the window should do:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    // I don't care for SourceInitialized (also remove it from XAML)
}
```

In App.xaml or wherever a window is created:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        var window = new MainWindow();
        window.SourceInitialized += window_SourceInitialized;
        window.Show();
    }

    void window_SourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var window = sender as MainWindow;

        // I know how to handle this event for this window instance
    }
}
```